# JSTL Populate server-side variables

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Download the NetBeans project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bywd3NqVCRsFSEZQWHFROC1TZGM/edit?usp=sharing). File -> Download

Using [JSTL 1.2](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) I'm trying to get my web app to remember my input and then place it into the input box for me after submitting the form but for some reason it doesn't remember it. I just have 1 `.java` class and `.jsp` file.

**PersonController.java**

```
package controller;

public class PersonController {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="controller.PersonController" %>

<jsp:useBean id="personController" class="controller.PersonController" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="personController" property="name" param="name"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>PersonController</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
            <input name="name" maxlength="30" type="text" id="name" value="<c:out value="${personController.name}"/>"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Remember my name">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Errors**

1. HTTP Status 500 - /index.jsp (line: 4, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute controller.PersonController is invalid.
2. If it does not show error #1 then it will not populate the input field `name` after posting with previous input.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work.

The `<jsp:useBean>` looks for some bean with name `personController` in default scope, which is page, and provides it for other parts of your JSP, which is the html input tag in your case. But nobody has set this bean into the pageScope, so the `useBean` will create new instance of PersonController and put there. The name value is therefore null.

If you don't use any redirects, you can simply fill the input's value according to HTTP request's parameter:

```
<input name="name" value="<c:out value="${param.name}"/>">
```

If you are using HTTP redirect (you should after sending POST request), you can store the `name` into session.

```
<jsp:useBean id="personController" class="controller.PersonController" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="personController" property="name" param="name"/>
```

The `<jsp:setProperty>` sets the name property of the previously found (or created) bean `personalController` to the value of the request parameter with name `name`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me, can you please delete so that my question remains unanswered?

Comment: The error is related to the 4.th line, which is `useBean` - from your code. It looks like the PersonController is not available as WEB-INF/classes/controller/PersonController. You'll get this error even without the suggested `setProperty` tag.

Comment: Another reason, for your class being invalid, is that the JSP can't recognize it. Try to add `import="controller.PersonController"` into `<%@ page ... %>` directive.

Comment: We have to first fix the `class attribute controller.PersonController is invalid` problem, but I'm out of ideas. Can you double check your exception stacktrace for any other hints? Such as ClassNotFoundException...

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, I debug your code and you created one parameterized constructor. You need to add default constructor in your PersonController class. It will resolve your "The value for the useBean class attribute controller.PersonController is invalid" error.

For the value being set, You are using Controller and provided doGet method but it has not been defined as Servlet Class, It is a normal java class. You need to extend it with HttpServlet class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to remember your input after you submit,there do not need PersonController.java.
just write like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>PersonController</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
            <input name="name" maxlength="30" type="text" id="name" value="<c:out value="${param.name}"/>"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Remember my name">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```